# Accessing UI context from asynch task

Tags: android, user-interface, multithreading

I came across [this android example](http://code.google.com/p/and-bookworm/source/browse/trunk/src/com/totsp/bookworm/ManageData.java?spec=svn251&r=251) that runs an AsyncTask from a UI thread. The class ExportDatabaseTask is declared and instantiated in the Activity, and apparently it is possible to reference the activity's UI context from the onPreExecute and onPostExecute events, like this:

```
public class ManageData extends Activity { 

  private ExportDatabaseTask exportDatabaseTask; 
  [...]

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    [...]
    ManageData.this.exportDatabaseTask = new ExportDatabaseTask(); 
    ManageData.this.exportDatabaseTask.execute(); 
    [...]
  } 

  private class ExportDatabaseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> { 
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ManageData.this); 

    protected void onPreExecute() { 
      this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting database..."); 
      this.dialog.show(); 
    } 

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) { 
      [...]
    } 

    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) { 
      if (this.dialog.isShowing()) { 
         this.dialog.dismiss(); 
      } 
    } 
}
```

I am trying to refactor this so that the ExportDatabaseTask is declared in another class that is not the Activity, for various reasons, and I can't quite figure out how to make it work. I am lacking some basic Java concepts here, which I readily admit.

Specifically, myActivity is null in onPreExecute(). Why is that?

```
// this is a click event handler in my activity that starts the export
public void onClick(View v) {
  Exporter ex = new Exporter(getApplicationContext(), ActivityMain.this);
  ex.exportDatabaseTask.execute();
} 

//this is the utility class
public class Exporter {

    public ExportDatabaseTask exportDatabaseTask;   
    private Context myContext;
    private ActivityMain myActivity;

    public Exporter(Context ctx, ActivityMain act) {
            myContext = ctx;
            myActivity = act;

            this.exportDatabaseTask = new ExportDatabaseTask(); 
    }

    public class ExportDatabaseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
            private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(myContext);

       // can use UI thread here?
       protected void onPreExecute() {
         // ====> this throws a Nullpointer exception:
         myActivity.dialog.setMessage("Exporting database...");
         myActivity.dialog.show();
       }

       protected Boolean doInBackground(final Void... args) {
      }

       protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
         if (myActivity.dialog.isShowing()) {
           myActivity.dialog.dismiss();
         }
       }
     }
}
```

I realize that I can take the code from the pre and post-execute events and put it into the onclick handler in my activity, avoiding this question, but I am still curious why the code above does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule #1: Never use `getApplicationContext()` to get a `Context`. `Activity` is a `Context`. You do not need another `Context`, and the `Context` you get from `getApplicationContext()` is utterly unusable for GUI-related operations.

Now, with that out of the way...

> apparently it is possible to reference
>   the activity's UI context from the
>   onPreExecute and onPostExecute events

`ExportDatabaseTask` is a private [inner class](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Nested_Classes) of the `Activity`. Inner classes in Java have access to the methods and data members of their outer class.

> Specifically, myActivity is null in
>   onPreExecute(). Why is that?

I doubt it is. I suspect that dialog is `null` inside of `myActivity`. That too will give you a `NullPointerException` on the indicated line.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I decided that it is not a good idea for such a utility class to contain UI code and I moved the dialogs to the caller.